# Trigger the plugin only if appoiment has been closed

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

He dear ,I have got a problem 
I have to fire a plugin only if klick on the button appointment closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by using SetState and SetStateDynamicEntity messages. Based on messages
InputParameter will change accordingly. in that way you have to trigger the plugin. Here the code below for your reference.

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("EntityMoniker") && 
context.InputParameters["EntityMoniker"] is EntityReference) 
{ 
EntityReference myEntity = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["EntityMoniker"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that but you can register your plugin on statuschange or on update and the watch statecode.

//statecodes
http://mostlymscrm.blogspot.co.at/2012/06/entity-statecodes-and-statuscodes.html

if (targetEntity.Contains("statecode") && targetEntity.getAttributeValue("statecode").Value == 2){
//myCode
}